# How to repeat the alphabet with for loop in caesar cipher in C#

Tags: c#, for-loop, encryption

I am making a Caesar cipher and I want to make the letters in a loop so for example if the letter 'z' needs to be shifted it should go back to 'a' for both capital and lowercase.

```
//Array that holds each char in the plaintext inputed is declared and initiated
char[] chars = plainTextInput.ToCharArray();

//For loop that will go through each letter and change the value of each letter by adding the shiftAmount
for (int i = 0; i < plainTextInput.Length; ++i)
{   
    chars[i] = (char)(((int)chars[i]) + shiftAmount);

    if (chars[i] >= 97 && chars[i] <= 122)
    {
        if (chars[i] > 122)
        {
            int x = chars[i] - 123;
            chars[i] = (char)((int)(97 + x));
        }
    }
}  

//Variable for ciphertext output holds char array chars as a string
cipherTextOutput = new string(chars);
```

If I input `'xyz'` and shift by one I get `'yz{'`.

Comment: Add the logic to check if you're reading a `z`... a translation table... you have a number of options.

Comment: @JeffMercado So how many translation tables do you need to accommodate an arbitrary shift amount?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ: Well naturally a translation table would be impractical if it was necessary to support arbitrary shift counts.  That's not really an issue here as it was not stated that it needed it (and it's fairly clear that the shift count here is 1).  We don't necessarily need to generalize every single question here.

Comment: @JeffMercado The OP does have a variable called `shiftAmount`. I don't think it would make sense for it to be there if s/he just wanted to always shift by 1.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ: Ah, good eyes, I totally missed (ignored) that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use modulo arithmetic:

```
new_pos = (current_pos + shift) % 26
```

`current_pos` has to be the relative letter position (eg: `a=0, b=1... z=25`). Something like:

```
if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z')      // uppercase
{
    current_pos = (int) c - (int) 'A';
}
else if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') // lowercase
{
    current_pos = (int) c - (int) 'a';
}
```

#### See working demo: http://ideone.com/NPZbT

---

That being said, I hope this is just code you are playing with, and not something to be used in real code.